# Git branch is torn in 2 parts having individual names. How to sew them together in 1 branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

Here is the structure of my local Git repository. As one can see, there is a discontinuity, gap between branches *master* and *remotes/tpt3/master*. But there must be only 1 continious branch so that the commits of *master* should go after the last commit of *remotes/tpt3/master* and only 1 branch must contain all these commits.
[image]
When I try to use the command:

```
$git rebase --onto remotes/tpt3/master master
```

it leads to the following wrong result. [image]
First, *master* should go after *remotes/tpt3/master*.
Second, the commits of *master* disapperead somewhere.

Could You be so kind to tell which Git command I should use to make 1 continious branch from *master* and *remotes/tpt3/master*?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want to achieve... But I've noticed you used rebase "--onto". Have you tried a rebase without it? [This link explains the difference](https://ilya.puchka.me/git-rebase-vs-git-rebase-onto/), maybe you can verify yourself if it would meet your needs...

Comment: Excuse me, please. I want to push 2 commits of master branch up to the remote/tpt3/master branch (so that they were the last commits of remote/tpt3/master branch) and delete master branch, so that there would be only one branch left -  remote/tpt3/master branch. For convenience of my work and for simple pushing only 1 branch to the Gitlab server repository.

Comment: Couldn't you cherry-pick the commits you would like to pick to your branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top note: the commands you will use here are:

```
git add              # insert arguments as needed here
git commit
git replace --graft master~2 tpt3/master
```

(inspect the result here to make sure it all worked)

```
git filter-branch -- master
```

(inspect the result again)

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original | xargs git update-ref -d
```

(inspect yet again), and:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

to remove the `F'` commit from `master` (see below), then `git push tpt3 master`.

Read the below carefully before doing anything, and consider making a backup of your repository before starting!

---

Side note: `gitk` is a serviceable (although not great) commit *viewer* but `gitk` images are terrible for questions on StackOverflow.  I've retyped some crucial bits from that first image here, although I may have inserted any number of typographic errors:

```
- Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index
* (master) Commit 22.10.21. Just verified Fe-Fe nuc...
* Initial commit.t Np=100100000 TITAN YEILD COUNT=9...

* (remotes/tpt3/master) After quarantine. STEP #29
* After Quarantine. STEP #28
* After Quarantine. STEP #27
```

This represents a total of five commits, in two separate (disjoint) DAGs.  Each of the two graphs contains two or three commits arranged in a linear fashion.  (NB: the second image shows that the first image is a lie, so *caveat emptor:* I'm working from the lie.  You'll need to apply your own brain to the following.)

If we assign letter codes to each commit, and if we make the uncommitted work into a third commit on the current branch, we get:

```
F: Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index
E: (master) Commit 22.10.21. Just verified Fe-Fe nuc...
D: Initial commit.t Np=100100000 TITAN YEIDL COUNT=9...

C: (remotes/tpt3/master) After quarantine. STEP #29
B: After Quarantine. STEP #28
A: After Quarantine. STEP #27
```

The two commit graphs are then:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- remotes/tpt3/master

D <-E <-F   <-- master
```

It seems like you'd like to have:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- remotes/tpt3/master
         \
          D <-E <-F   <-- master
```

You can't *quite* get this because commits `D` and `E` already exist and therefore cannot be changed, but they *can* be *copied* to new improved commits that are otherwise very much like `D` and `E` respectively.  (Commit `F` doesn't actually exist yet, but you'll need to make it, to save the working tree contents, unless you do all your work in a separate clone or added working tree, neither of which is much benefit: just make commit `F` and then we'll copy it the same way we do with `D` and `E`.  You can then boot commit `F'`—the copy—off the end of the chain while keeping the work in your working tree, using `git reset`.)

You can *almost*, but not quite, make the new improved commits using `git rebase`.  You tried this already but used the wrong command:

> ```
> $git rebase --onto remotes/tpt3/master master
> ```

What `git rebase` does can be thought of as (and depending on your Git version, now *is*, or else approximates) repeated cherry-picking.  Each cherry-pick operation copies one commit.  The crucial parts of this process are:

1. `git rebase` must list out *all the commits to copy*.  This is where your incorrect arguments are biting you now, as [Leonardo Alves Machado commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496018/git-branch-is-torn-in-2-parts-having-individual-names-how-to-sew-them-together#comment124617096_70496018).  Running `git rebase --onto remotes/tpt3/master` requires that you then list which commits *not to copy* from the current branch; you say *do not copy any commits up to and including the latest one on `master`*, which results in copying *no* commits.  Fixing this—by using `git rebase remotes/tpt3/master` instead—would attempt to cherry-pick (copy) all `master`-branch commits, which is much closer to what you want.  It still won't quite work—probably—because of step 3 below.
2. The rebase code now does a *detached HEAD* style checkout or switch to the target (`--onto` or otherwise specified) commit.  In this case you want to use the `remotes/tpt3/master` commit, `After quarantine. STEP #29`.
3. The rebase code now repeatedly runs `git cherry-pick` or equivalent.  Each cherry-pick turns a commit into a change-set, and then copies that change-set atop the current commit and commits the result.  For two of the three to-be-copied commits, `E` and `F`, this is the correct action.  However, commit `D` has no parent, so cherry-pick will simply consider each file *in* commit `D` as added-from-scratch.  This is likely to cause a big mess of add/add conflicts: each "copy" step is actually a three-way merge and this merge is likely to go wrong here.
4. Last, having copied all the commits, `git rebase` [wrests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrest) the branch name of the branch you were on *before* step 2 so that it now points to the *current* commit, which is the last-copied commit or—in your case where you copied *no* commits—the commit Git checked out in step 2.

The cure for this particular problem—where step 3 thinks of every commit as an add/add conflict-is *probably* to use `git replace` to make a *graft* that makes Git pretend that commit `D` has commit `C` as a parent.  Once the graft is in place, you have:

```
A--B--C   <-- remotes/tpt3/master
       :
        D--E--F   <-- master
```

This sort of vague pretend link won't *quite* do the job, but using `git filter-branch` or [the new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) can then "cement the graph into place" by replacing commits `D`, `E`, and `F` with new commits `D'`, `E'`, and `F'` that—except for having different hash IDs themselves<sup>1</sup> and referring back to `C`, `D'`, and `E'` respectively—are otherwise identical to `D`, `E`, and `F`: they have the same snapshot, and mostly the same metadata.  That is, post-filter-branch / filter-repo, you now have:

```
A--B--C   <-- remotes/tpt3/master
       \
        D'-E'-F'  <-- master
```

which is what you want.  You can now run `git push tpt3 master` safely; this will add on the three commits.

Since you probably just want two commits plus uncommitted changes, we can now use `git reset` to kick commit `F'` off `master`.  Note that commit `F'` continues to exist in your repository (as do commits `D-E-F`) for some time, but with no easy way to *find* the commits, you won't *see* them.  It will be as if they had never existed.  Eventually—after 30 days or more—Git will notice that they're not being used and discard them for real.

So, at this point you just run:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

to tell Git to:

1. move the current branch name back one step;
2. reset its index as well, but leave your working tree unchanged.

You'll now have:

```
A--B--C   <-- remotes/tpt3/master
       \
        D'-E'  <-- master
```

with uncommitted work, as you wanted.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since the commit hash ID *is* the *true name* of the commit, this means that `D'` is completely different from `D`, for instance.  The fact that they have the same snapshot and mostly the same metadata is not of interest to Git—at least not at this level—because Git cares only and entirely about the *hash ID* at this level.  So it's a little like the old joke, ["Other than that, Mrs Lincoln, how was the play?"](https://howlround.com/really-how-was-play-mrs-lincoln)—except in this scenario Abe has been replaced by a clone that no one (except maybe Mrs Lincoln) can detect.